# need to select customer ids whose first purchase in 2000 - sql

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am writing a query to create a list for target audience for a marketing campaign. The list should follow the following criteria:
-Credit card number starts with 100 0r 110
-Customer lives in city A 
-Customer's credit card does not exist in the Campaign table. 
- Customer has a phone number (There are two columns for phone numbers PHONE1 and PHONE2) 
-Customer has an email 
-First Purchase date to be in 2000

```
SELECT cust_id
min(purchase_date) = 2000 
FROM customers
WHERE cardno not in (SELECT cardno FROM campaign WHERE cust_cardno = 
campaign.cardno) 
AND City = "A"
AND Email IS NOT NULL
AND cardno LIKE '[100-110]%'
AND PHONE1, PHONE2 IS NOT NULL 
OR PHONE1 IS NOT NULL
OR PHONE2 IS NOT NULL;
```

Some of the queries are not correct, they are:
1) Credit card number starts with 100 0r 110  -> AND cardno LIKE '[100-110]%'
2) Customer has a phone number (There are two columns for phone numbers PHONE1 and PHONE2) -> 
    AND PHONE1, PHONE2 IS NOT NULL 
    OR PHONE1 IS NOT NULL
    OR PHONE2 IS NOT NULL
3)First Purchase date to be in 2000 -> min(purchase_date) = 2000
What are the mistakes in these queries?

Comment: What is expected output ? and also provide sample data.

Comment: `*` is used as wildcard in MS Access instead of `%`.

Comment: The expected output is a list of customers who fir the criteria

Comment: What is problem with your current output

Comment: min(purchase_date) = 2000 is wrong as when I tried it separately. This is also the case for AND cardno LIKE '[100-110]%' even when I used *. and also the phone number criteria is not achieved.

Answer (score 1):

check this

```
SELECT c.cust_id
FROM customers c
WHERE cardno not in (SELECT cardno FROM campaign ) 
AND City = "A"
AND Email IS NOT NULL
AND (cardno LIKE '[100]*' OR  cardno LIKE '[110]*')
AND  (PHONE1 IS NOT NULL
OR PHONE2 IS NOT NULL)
AND 
year(purchase_date) = 2000 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple errors.  For instance, `min()` with no `group by`.  Filtering after aggregation, but no `having`.  Filtering conditions connected by commas.  Missing commas and so on.

So, I think you want:

```
SELECT cust_id
FROM customers as c
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM campaign ca WHERE ca.cardno = c.cust_cardno) AND
      City = "A"
      Email IS NOT NULL AND
      LEFT(cardno, 3) IN ('100', '110') AND
      (PHONE1 IS NOT NULL OR
       PHONE2 IS NOT NULL 
      )
GROUP BY cust_id
HAVING min(purchase_date) = 2000 ;
```

Note that I replaced the `NOT IN` with `NOT EXISTS`.  `NOT IN` does not work as expected if any of the returned rows are `NULL`.

I also modified the "start with" logic.

Comment: What does Group By do when we have the first query of selcet sut_id? Don't they do the same thing?

Comment: @user233531 . . . There is no `sut_id` in this answer, so I don't know what your comment is referring to.

Comment: Obviously I meant "cust_id" not "sut_id"